# convert output received to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have selected some fields from a json file and I saved its name along with its respective comment to do preprocessing..

Below are the codes:

```
import re
import json


with open('C:/Users/User/Desktop/Coding/parsehubjsonfileeg/all.json', encoding='utf8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

# dictionary for element which you want to keep
new_data = {'selection1': []}
print(new_data)
# copy item from old data to new data if it has 'reviews'
for item in data['selection1']:
    if 'reviews' in item:
        new_data['selection1'].append(item)
        print(item['reviews'])
        print('--')

# save in file
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(new_data, f)
    selection1 = new_data['selection1']
    for item in selection1:
        name = item['name']
        print('>>>>>>>.', name)
        CommentID = item['reviews']
        for com in CommentID:
            comment = com['review'].lower()  # converting all to lowercase
            result = re.sub(r'\d+', '', comment)  # remove numbers
            results = (result.translate(
                str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))).strip()  # remove punctuations and white spaces
            comments = (results)
            print(comment)
```

my output is:

```
>>>>>>>. Heritage The Villas
we booked at villa valriche through mari deal for 2 nights and check-in was too lengthy (almost 2 hours) and we were requested to make a deposit of rs 10,000 or credit card which we were never informed about it upon booking.
lovely place to recharge.
one word: suoerb
definitely not a 5 star. extremely poor staff service.
>>>>>>>. Oasis Villas by Evaco Holidays
excellent
spent 3 days with my family and really enjoyed my stay. the advantage of oasis is its privacy - with 3 children under 6 years, going to dinner/breakfast at hotels is often a burden rather than an enjoyable experience. 
staff were very friendly and welcoming. artee and menni made sure everything was fine and brought breakfast - warm croissants - every morning. atish made the check-in arrangements - and was fast and hassle free.
will definitely go again!
```

what should I perform to convert this output to a dataframe having column name and comment?

Comment: This may be helpfull? https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/conversion-functions-in-pandas-dataframe/

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: I tried this ```df=pd.DataFrame({"name":[name],
                 "comment":[comment]})```  and I got this as output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVL5V.png

Comment: @Nedisha What's wrong with that output? In the code you shared, why is the loop `for item in selection1` inside of the context manager for `f` ? As far as I can tell, `f` is never used after you've written the JSON.

Comment: We're probably going to need a [mcve], or at least some information on the data in the crucial parts of the program.

Comment: my json looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi03M.png

Comment: I used f as a variable to represent the json and ```data = json.load(f)``` will load the json file I have imported